# Apex Test coverage issue?

Tags: unit-test

```
Any one can help me how to cover the commented lines?
    Between the commented lines of code is not covered...

Apex class:
    public with sharing class Hoursprojectpopupcls{
    public boolean ccRequst{get;set;}
    public musqot__Costcentre__c ccRec{get;set;}
    public Hoursprojectpopupcls(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
            hrs = new Allocation_resources__c ();

    public void ccUserRec(){
    string sObjName =Id.valueof(ccId).getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
             if(sObjName=='musqot__Costcentre__c'){
    /******************************************************/                 
    ccRec=[SELECT Id,  owner.name, OwnerId, Name 
                           FROM  Costcentre__c 
                           where Id =:ccId];
                    if(ccRec.OwnerId== UserInfo.getUserId()){                                      
                       ccRequst=false;
                    }
                    else{                        
                       ccRequst=true;          
                    }
              }
    /******************************************************/

    Apex test class:
    @isTest
    public class HoursprojectpopupclsTest{
        static testMethod void Hoursprojectpopup(){
          Costcentre__c objCC=new Costcentre__c(); 
          objCC.Name='test';
          objCC.cc_Owner__c=u2.id;
          objCC.Headline__c ='present';
          insert objCC;
          System.assertEquals('test', objCC.name);
          ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(objCC);
            Hoursprojectpopupcls hrsprojpopup = new Hoursprojectpopupcls(sc);
          hrsprojpopup .ccUserRec();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible answers:

1. You are passing a record of object type of Costcentre__c from the test class but in the function you are checking with 'musqot__Costcentre__c'.
2. In the test class, the line `objCC.cc_Owner__c=u2.id;` is setting some field value, I hope this doesnt affect the standard OwnerId field of the record. Plus create 2 records with different OwnerId and call the function twice to cover the inner if else conditions(`ccRec.OwnerId== UserInfo.getUserId()`)

Add this in your test class.

```
User otherOwner = [SELECT Id from User where isActive = true and Id != :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1]; //This will give you another active user other than you.
    //Now when creating records in test class, 
    Costcentre__c objCC=new Costcentre__c(); 
              objCC.Name='test';
              objCC.cc_Owner__c=u2.id;
              objCC.Headline__c ='present';
              objCC.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(); // you are the owner
              insert objCC;
    Costcentre__c objCC2=new Costcentre__c(); 
              objCC2.Name='test';
              objCC2.cc_Owner__c=u2.id;
              objCC2.Headline__c ='present';
              objCC2.OwnerId = otherOwner.Id// Other user is the owner.
              insert objCC2;
```

Then call the function twice with 2 different CC records just created.

Comment: cc_Owner__c filed is lookup to user object.

Comment: That's I can see from your code. Did you check the 1st point? Try replacing musqot__Costcentre__c with only Costcentre__c

Comment: can you suggest me how to create 2 records with different ownerid's?

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: Dont forget to mark your test class SeeAllData=true like this. `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`

Comment: @SantanuHalder marking your tests with SellAllData=true is bad practise. As you can image, you could potentially update production data within your test classes!

Comment: @MahatHussein, are you sure test classes can update org data? I believe all the changes made in test classes get discarded after completion of test.

Comment: @SantanuHalder my bad - my example is incorrect you are right its transient, the issue with using seealldata actually comes about when you are doing deployments. Expecting data to be present across all your orgs can only mean one thing...failed tests and failed deployments. Thats why its best to create your own data.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Its always better to create independent test classes. But since the query is related to User, I went for it. There is quite a high chance that some users will be there before deployment. Cheers!